# What is the best way to name nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I found there are several ways to name a node (please relate to the MWE for more) but I am wondering if there are other (rather "simple") ways of doing this:

1. My current 'best practice', it works with 2 `node` commands in a `\draw` command.
2. My second way of doing this, it's very useful when paths based on names of nodes shall be produced, which again is useful when an axis is scaled individually and therefor all other measures within a scope.
3. The initial attempt which actually does not work as intended and lead to nr. 2.

Would anyone happen to have some advice to simplify the code? Or what else could be done? I'd appreciate anyh ints!

[image: Display]

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
booktabs,
tikz
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.2,6.2);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x}; %X-Achse
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y}; %Y-Achse
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
    %
    \begin{scope}[color=black]
    %1.
    \filldraw (2,1) circle (0.08cm) node (A) {} node[anchor=north,fill=white,yshift=-0.1cm]{A};
    %2.
    \filldraw (4,2) circle (0.08cm) node[anchor=west,fill=white] (B) {B};
    %3.
    \filldraw (3,5) circle (0.08cm) node[anchor=south,fill=white,yshift=0.1cm]{C};
    \node (C) at (3,5) {};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Your foreach loops are drawing independent paths so you can use one loop and many paths instead of one for each path. For example, just combine those four paths and use only `\x`. For the node placement you can use `\node at (\x,0cm) {\x}` instead of using a `\draw` each time.

Comment: Did you want to name a node for further use or did you mean you want a better way to set the **text** beside the node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution with a different approach: name your coordinates then add the labels.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.2,6.2);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x}; %X-Achse
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y}; %Y-Achse
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
    % triangle with coordinates
    \draw[very thick]
    (2,1) coordinate (A)
    -- (4,2) coordinate (B)
    -- (3,5) coordinate (C)
    -- cycle;
    %
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/below left,B/right,C/above}{
      \filldraw (\pt) circle(.8mm) node[\labpos=1.5mm,fill=white]{\pt};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting. That's definitely a new one to me, plus it looks simpler. I think this also helped me a bit with defining `\foreach`-commands.